# Count the number of Factors using while Loop on Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, while-loop

I am new to Python and so I am a little unaware of the advanced functions. Here's how I approached this problem by breaking it into two .

First I found the factors of this number.

```
a = int(input("Enter Number to find Factors: "))
b = 1
while a >= b :
  if a % b == 0 :
    print(b)
  b+=1
```

Second, I prepared the psudo code for counting numbers

```
b = 17 
count = 0
while b > 0 :
  rem = b % 10
  b = b // 10
  count += 1 
print(count)
```

can you guys help me how should I proceed like how should I join these I think I am having problem with syntax

Comment: If you want to count factors of `a` why don't you simply increment the count after the statement `print(b)`?  The value of count after the while loop will be the number of factors.  It's unclear the purpose of the 2nd while loop.

Comment: What do you mean "counting numbers"? Your second snippet is to count the _number of digits_ in a number. If you want to count how many numbers are factors of `a`, then simply keep track when you check if it's a factor. If it's something else, please give more details. Including example input and expected output in your question would help. Please take the [tour], read [what's on-topic here](/help/on-topic), [ask],
and the [question checklist](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260648/843953). Welcome to  Stack Overflow!

Answer (score 0):

Modify your first solution to increase the count each time one is found.

```
a = int(input("Enter Number to find Factors: "))
b = 1
count = 0
while a >= b :
    if a % b == 0 :
        count += 1
        print(b)
    b+=1
```

Comment: OP should also note that the code will go a lot faster if the loop  breaks when a/2 > b. It will literally take half as long.

Comment: True, good suggestion about the a/2.  But don't forget that in that way the a has to be added separately in the end because a is also a factor of a.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you were asking for?

```
def get_factors(n, list):
    b = 1
    while n >= b :
        if n % b == 0 :
            list.append(b)
        b+=1

def count_digits(n):
    count = 0
    while n > 0 :
        n = n // 10
        count += 1 
    return count

n = int(input("Enter Number to find Factors: "))

# getting the list of factors
factors = list()
get_factors(n, factors) 

# printing the factors and the amount of digits in each factor
for f in factors:
    print("Factor:", f, ", Digits:", count_digits(f))
```

Every time you want to join more than one piece of code you can create a function using:

```
def function_name(parameters)
```

Then put your code inside the function or functions and you can apply the functions to whatever variables you want.

You can create functions that don't return anything. Those can be used like this:

```
function_name(parameters)
```

Or you can create functions that return values and they can be used like this:

```
a = function_name(parameters)
```

For more information you can check w3school they explain it well: https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_functions.asp

Comment: Thanks For the answer but sadly I Haven't learned about Def function

Comment: I gave you another answer without using def. I hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

In this answer I show how to connect the codes without using def.

**You can just copy the second code and paste it inside of the if of the first one:**

```
a = int(input("Enter Number to find Factors: "))
b = 1
while a >= b :
  if a % b == 0 :
    b2 = b
    count = 0
    while b2 > 0 :
        b2 = b2 // 10
        count += 1 
    print(b, count)
  b+=1
```

remember to copy the value of b to a different variable.